# Accessing JSON data using SwiftyJSON and Alamofire

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I've created a function that successfully returns a JSON object through a POST request using Alamofire, and I can print the object with the correct data. However, if I want to access a certain data point within the JSON, it either prints as null or says I am accessing it the wrong way. Here is my code structure, I'm wondering how to properly write the part that says print(post.description)

func parseJSON(id:String, found: Bool) -> Dictionary {
    var dsProperties = String:JSON

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlPath, parameters: parameters)
  .responseJSON { (request, response, result) in
    if let anError = result.error {

      print("error calling POST on /posts")
      print(anError)
    }

    if let result: AnyObject = result.value {
      let post: JSON = JSON(result)
      for (index: String, subJSON: JSON) in post {
        print(post.description) // how can i subscript this
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: is `description` a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `subscription` section in [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#subscript):

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlPath, parameters: parameters)
  .responseJSON { (request, response, result) in
if let anError = result.error {

  print("error calling POST on /posts")
  print(anError)
}

if let result: AnyObject = result.value {
  let post: JSON = JSON(result)
  for (index: String, subJSON: JSON) in post {
    print(post["description"].stringValue)
  }
}
```

}

In case it's not a string, switch `stringValue`for the appropriate data type